# How to draw a shaded area between two lines

Tags: java, swing

How do you draw a shaded area between two lines of a certain color?

I'm using `Graphics2D.drawLine()` to draw the lines and to have a translucent shaded area of color between the lines.

Comment: I am not sure, how to do this, but can't you use a brighter colour than the one used to draw the line, to draw another line which will act as a shade, by doing something like yourChosenColor.brighter().brighter or darker().darker(), which ever you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

This should possible with [GradientPaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html)

Somthing like that:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(0,100);
    p.addPoint(100,100);
    p.addPoint(100,200);
    p.addPoint(100,200);

    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 100.0f, Color.red,
             200.0f, 200.0f, Color.green, true);
    g2.setPaint(gp);
    g2.fill(p);
}
```

For transparency you need to include settings for the alpha channel.

```
g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
          alpha));
```

For working examples see [this article](http://marioyohanes.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/how-to-gradient-paint/)

Comment: +1 See also this related [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) that uses translucent gradient paint.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking the wrong way around. If you want to draw an area, do so. Render the lines on top of the area afterwards.
Areas can be rendered with Graphics.drawPolygon.

There are two ways to get translucency. The simplest way (for solid color) is to create the Color instance with alpha (new Color(0xAARRGGBB, true) and use that for drawing.
The other way is to use Graphics2D.setComposite with an instance of AlphaComposite (that method also affects the drawing of element that do not make use of the color, e.g. drawImage).